# InAppReview : SKStoreReviewController So Slow

Tags: ios, swift, skstorereviewcontroller

Using SKStoreReviewController for inAppReview takes time until the prompt appears, is there any way to make it show faster ?

Also, submit button is always dimmed, not allowing me to rate, is this because i didn't upload app to appstore yet?

[image]

```
import StoreKit
protocol InAppReviewProtocol {
   func requestInAppReview()
}

extension InAppReviewProtocol {

    func requestInAppReview() {
        if #available(iOS 10.3, *) {
            SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            if let appStoreLink = URL(string: Constants.shareApp.url) {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(appStoreLink)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No, you can not make is faster, the system decides when to show the alert.
Read [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview) on `SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()` for more details.

The submit button is disabled as long as you run your app via XCode to prevent you from giving yourself lots of 5-star votings ;)

Answer (score 0):

See below from the apple docs of `requestReview` method:-

> Although you should call this method when it makes sense in the user
>   experience flow of your app, the actual display of a rating/review
>   request view is governed by App Store policy. Because this method may or may not present an alert, it's not appropriate to call it in response to a button tap or other user action.

For more details,
 go to 
this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skstorereviewcontroller/2851536-requestreview)

So you got the answer for your first question. Your second question is just simple, in development mode you cannot give rating as it makes sense also. You have to publish your app to appStore first and download app from there and can give a review.

Hope it helps you..